# Dotnet application process suddenly crashes on host startup

Tags: .net

Depending on where you're looking the code is different. In the console it's saying code `-2147483645` and in the output window it is code `2147483651`. I can't find anything relevant for both codes. Both places list the same process id.

The project I'm running is dotnet 6 WPF application, which spins up an ASP.NET Core API as a separate process as part of it's initialization process:

```
Task.Run(() => JudgeApi.Start(provider) // provider is IServiceProvider
```

The Api entrypoint looks like this:

```
 Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
     .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder
         => webBuilder
             .ConfigureServices(services
                 => services.AddSingleton<IJudgeServiceProvider>(new JudgeServiceProvider(appServiceProvider)))
             .UseUrls("http://*:11337")
             .UseStartup<Startup>())
     .Build()
     .Run();
```

This is done because the WPF app communicates with mobile apps over local network. Having it spawn it's own API with shared service container simplifies the architecture.

The app exits the moment it attempts to run `Host.CreateDefaultBuilder`. It's not related to the `Startup` class or any other web builder logic, because I've also tried to comment all of it.

Finally, the project has previously worked on this machine and also works as intended on another machine right now. Both systems are running Windows 10 with installed dotnet 7, dotnet 8 SDKs.

I've tried clearing all local nuget cache and bin, obj directories and try-catching everywhere - no result. Happens both in debug and release mode (with a release build I've used in the field previously)

#### Edit

If I build a release version on pcA (where it's not working) and run it  on pcB (where debugging is working working) it doesn't work. But if I build it on pcB still does not work on pcA.

At this point I've done clean reinstallation of VisualStudio and all dotnet SDKs. Running out of ideas here..

#### Edit 2

repo is [open-source](https://github.com/Not-Endurance/not-timing-system/tree/master), if anyone wanna try to repro, but honestly I think it's something PC specific. Set `EMS.Judge` as startup project and go.

Comment: Do you get an exception? What is the message and stack trace?

Comment: @Charlieface No exception.

Comment: Is there any chance you have a `StackOverflowException` anywhere?  That can result in mysterious exits with no apparent stack trace.

Comment: @dbc same branch is running like a charm on another PC, not any local changes.

Comment: Just guessing here but could it be some concurrency/timing issue where the ASP.NET Core API process calls back into the dotnet 6 WPF application during or after it's startup and the problem is only apparent if the callback occurs before the WPF app is finished?  Something like that can sometimes happen with lazy type initializers.

Comment: Need more code context than this.  You say "... which spins up an ASP.NET Core API as a separate process". Which means to me, you should be using `Process.Start()` but you have `Task.Run()`, which I would advise against using at all unless it's to unblock the UI thread from doing CPU-bound work.

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't make sense to me. Why would you run an API application from Task.Run() and not Process.Start()?  Task.Run is for tasks, not entire applications.  I have never seen this done before.

Comment: @AdamVincent I'll try `Process.Start`, I've never heard of it before. I saw it done with `Task.Run` somewhere on the internets, I don't have a better defense :P

Comment: @AdamVincent `Process.Start` seems to require that I have a separately published API project that I can start as an exe. While this is certainly possible and probably way better solution for anything that scales, in this case it's not ideal as it introduces a 3rd application in my platform architecture. Then I would need to maintain duplicate in-memory state for the WPF and the API. Instead, when using `Task.Run` I can simply share state using the same DI container. And AFAIK there isn't anything wrong with manually spawning a background Task once during applications startup.

Comment: @dbc what do you mean "WPF app is finished"? Both apps are supposed to run alongside, in parallel. There isn't any callback as far as I can tell. Maybe it could be that something is going wrong with sharing the same DI services, but if that's the case then why does it still crash if I remove `ConfigureServices` and `Startup` from the API host build?

Comment: @Alex - sorry, I meant "before the WPF app is finished starting up."